# SKSpriteNode -- Texture not restored to original size after interrupting animateWithTextures

Tags: swift, animation, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skaction

I'm using `SKAction.animateWithTextures` to animate an `SKSpriteNode` in Swift, with parameter `restore` set to `true`. As described in [a different thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37579768/animate-an-skspritenode-with-textures-that-have-a-size-different-from-the-origin), a first problem arises because the images in the texture atlas are slightly larger than the original node. Now another problem has appeared: if I interrupt the animation using `SKSpriteNode.removeAllActions()`, then the node is restored to the original texture, but the size of the node is not restored to the original, resulting in a distorted image since the textures in the atlas are larger.

So, assuming I have my textures (slightly larger than the original one) in an array called `textures`, here's a snippet that should do it:

```
{
    // ... 
    sprite.runAction(SKAction.animateWithTextures(textures, timePerFrame: 1, resize: true, restore: true))
    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(3, target: self, selector: #selector(test), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    // ...
}
func test() {
    sprite.removeAllActions()
}
```

Note: this example using a timer only emulates a random interruption of the animation. In the game world, the animation may complete or be interrupted at some unknown time (typically when a contact occurs with another sprite).

After executing this, the sprite is restored to its original texture, but is stretched to match the size of the textures in the atlas. I've checked the `xScale` attribute, but of course it's `1.0`... Here's the visual result:

Before animation:

[image: Before animation]

During animation:

[image: During animation]

(notice how the image has shifted from its original position because SK keeps it centered :-( )

After animation:

[image: After animation has been cancelled]

(now she just looks fat)

Am I using this the wrong way, or is this a bug, or is there a way to fix it?

Thanks!

David

Answer (score 0):

I think you are removing the animation before it's natural cycle.

Try to add an action like:

```
let actionTexture = SKAction.animateWithTextures(textures, timePerFrame: 0.1, resize: true, restore: true)
sprite.runAction(actionTexture, count:30) // 30 x 0.1 = 3 sec tot animation
```

//REMOVE TIMER (or use action with wait)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The point is, I don't know in advance when the animation might be interrupted -- it's an event that may occur "randomly" while the `animateWithTextures` action is being performed, so I can't time it like this. What I'm hoping to achieve is that the action is carried out completely if nothing happens, but the sprite is reverted to its original state (original texture + size) when it gets interrupted. Again, the fact that the original texture is restored, but not the size, kind of looks like a bug to me, or there's some parameter I'm not setting properly.

Comment: Is hard to understand your bug, but you can force it at runaction with completion block, and set texture and size once the animation will finished